# SQL Conditional Unique Constraint With Where Clause Within Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, conditional-statements, unique-constraint

I have a table where I want to ensure that a combination of five columns remain unique within that table. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ__MyTable.MFG.Model.Class.Depiction.Iteration] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
        (
         [ManufacturerID] ASC,
         [Model] ASC,
         [BlockClassID] ASC,
         [BlockDepictionID] ASC,
         [BlockIterationID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
            ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
    ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want to exclude combinations where a sixth separate column has a particular value. For example, I only want to enforce this above constraint when the column [Flag] = 0 and exclude enforcement when the column [Flag] = 1 .

Comment: This sounds like composite primary key. But it has to be done on all rows. If you want composite unique key that is only active based on 6th column you would need to write `INSTEAD OF ` trigger.

Comment: Also - for this table there is a separate ID column [int] IDENTITY for  the PK.

Answer (score 22):

As workaround, You can get the proper ANSI behavior in SQL Server 2008 and above by creating a unique, filtered index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX__MyTable.MFG.Model.Class.Depiction.Iteration] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable] ([ManufacturerID],[Model],[BlockClassID],[BlockDepictionID],[BlockIterationID])
WHERE [Flag] = 0;
```

[TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)